# Grafana OAuth: Self Signed Certificate

Tags: grafana

**Brief**

- I am running Grafana on Docker
- I am connecting Keycloak with Grafana for signin
- I have followed all steps at https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/auth/generic-oauth/ and it works fine

**Problem**

- For HTTPS I have a self signed certificate at Keycloak
- At djnago I have this as `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=path_to_ca`

Within Grafana I am forced to set `GF_AUTH_GENERIC_OAUTH_TLS_SKIP_VERIFY_INSECURE=true` as I cannot find a way to mention CA path

Is there any way to set CA file path?

Comment: Update: I am running Grafana on Docker

Answer (score 3):

Grafana backend is written on Golang, which tries to use system CA certificates - https://golang.org/src/crypto/x509/root_linux.go:

```
// Possible certificate files; stop after finding one.
var certFiles = []string{
    "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt",                // Debian/Ubuntu/Gentoo etc.
    "/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt",                  // Fedora/RHEL 6
    "/etc/ssl/ca-bundle.pem",                            // OpenSUSE
    "/etc/pki/tls/cacert.pem",                           // OpenELEC
    "/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem", // CentOS/RHEL 7
    "/etc/ssl/cert.pem",                                 // Alpine Linux
}
```

So just try to add your own custom CA used for Keycloak to your system CA certs.

Comment: I am using Grafana Docker, would that mean any thing different?

Comment: No, also Grafana image contains own CA certs. It is the same - "mount" correct CA certs to the correct path in the container.

Comment: When configuring alert contact points, a contact point with a self signed root CA will trigger this error failing to post the webhook.
Adding root CAs may vary slightly across distros.
Copy the cert to /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors
Then run sudo update-ca-trust extract
This should update the files in /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/... which are typically linked back to /etc/pki/tls/certs
Cert not a root CA will fail to be extracted
You can verify your root CA prior with OpenSSL openssl x509 -noout -text -in <cert_file> | grep --after-context=2 "X509v3 Basic Constraints" | grep "CA:TRUE"